# Redirect to url without escaping any characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to redirect users to an external url for payment. I'm using redirect method:

```
redirect_to response[:url]
```

Sometimes, they get http status 400. I've found that the url may change. How can I redirect my users to the correct url?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do the trick:

`redirect_to CGI::unescape(response[:url])`